# How to seperate business logic from controllers in Express.js applications

Tags: express, controller, business-logic

During one of the interviews I got a question how to separate business logic from controller in Express. Would be that a correct solution?

```
const db =require('./db')
const helpers =require('./helpers')

exports.getBooksValue = (req, res)=>{
    const books   =  db.get(req.params)
    const booksValue = helpers.calculateBookValue(books)
    res.send(booksValue)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no correct(standard) solution in express whereas ruby on rails for example has mvc pattern in its standard way since express encourages more flexibility.

Your solution looks good, but if you are focusing on further seperation,

I suggest you to make `config` folder and managing db's information inside of that file.

Inside of config folder, make sure to seperate whether it is for production or development.

You can also use `dotenv` in config folder for importing env values more safely.